# Problems in parse JSON array

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "myData" : [
    [
      {
        "text" : "lorem ipsum",
        "id" : "myId"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And I want to get "text" and "id" values with SwiftyJSON.

**My code:**

```
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody), headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let id = json //json["myData"]["id"]... how get "id" ?
            print(id)
    }
```

Comment: `json["mydata"]` gives you an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: Please learn to read JSON, it's pretty easy. There are only two collection types: `{}` is dictionary (key subscripted), `[]` is array (index subscripted).

Comment: Is this really your JSON? `myData` is an array of arrays? Not sure about that design...

Comment: @rob yes, it is my JSON

Comment: `json["myData"][0][0]["text"]` and `json["myData"][0][0]["id"]`

Comment: @rob thx, it is worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're accessing an array of arrays so you'll need to subscript out the elements you want like `let id = json["myData"][0][0]["id"]`.